# Algebraic Topology and Robotics

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, research, robotics

How active is the current research scene on the application of algebraic and differential topology to robotics? I have spent a decent portion of time researching and reading introductory papers, but have struggled to determine if this field is very active or not. I've come to understand that algebraic topology as a field has slown down in recent times and given way to algebraic geometry, but I've also read that more computational applications of the former (Topological Data Analysis, for instance) are enjoying considerable attention.

I suppose a side question is also: to all the researchers on this site, how important is it to factor in how active a field of research is before planning to enter it? Should I follow my heart etc. etc., or is a pragmatic approach best?

For context: I'm a recent graduate of a Mathematics/Electrical Engineering double bachelor's degree, currently working at a robotics and automation firm, and I'm intensely interested in algebraic topology. I'm strongly considering pursuing postgrad studies in mathematics and then possibly onto academia, and this is the research avenue I'm currently most interested in, but I want to have some perspective about the state of the field.

Comment: "how important is it to factor in how active a field of research is" That depends on your goals. If you just want to do work out of passion, then it doesn't matter at all. But if you want to, say, make money, then it matters a lot. And I would say algebraic topology, or entire math, is not a correct choice.

Comment: @freakish Money is low on my priorities, I mainly ask because I've heard of algebraic topologists being shuffled toward algebraic geometry research as it's the more active field. I am passionate and I plan to work out of passion, but I'm just trying to keep some perspective given what I've read.